# Azure XS Virtual machine vs. AWS micro instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

I am using AWS micro instance for over a year and a half.

It is adequate for just serving a small website with SQLExpress. However it is [very](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html), [very](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1143764) **slow** in all other cases. It shows 98 to 100% CPU usage while installing any new software, opening, closing, configuring the various tools and servers.

Im planning to move to Azure VM XS instance. It will cost about the same, once Azure VM goes GA. Until then Azure VM costs 33% lower, with no guarantee of uptime. A clear plus is that Windows 8 Server, with IIS 8 and websockets is available.

**Can anyone share with me experience with Azure? Will I benefit from moving to Azure XS instance?**

EDIT
VM = Virtual machine
XS = Xtra Small
GA = General Availability
AWS = Amazon web services
IIS = Everyone knows :)

Answer (score 1):

The difference will be minimal. If you have just a small website with SQL Server, consider creating a standard shared/dedicated website there. You'll get better performance because running the admin tools on a XS/micro instance is just too slow (better leave MS infrastructure to manage it through the control panel).